# Weblogic 11g: Set indefinite lockout

Tags: weblogic

I'm looking through the documentation for OBIEE 11g Weblogic on User Lockout policy http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13951/core/index.html

There are `LockoutDuration` and `LockoutResetDuration` which set finite numbers for login attempts and duration before getting automatically unlocked.

Is there a way to set it so that a locked account stays locked until someone manually unlocks it?

Also, which schema and tables contain user account information and the audit trail of login attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Oracle Support, there is no indefinite lockout. However, the solution proposed is to set the lockout duration to a very large value.

> The maximum threshold value is 9223372036854775807 minutes which
>   comes around (17536635926176.287109) years.